# Can peer-to-peer systems be location aware?

Tags: routes, p2p, chord, kademlia

I have been reading about peer-to-peer systems like Chord and Kademlia and found out that while routing in the overlay may be optimized, it is not the same in the underlay. A request can actually have less hops but be routed across the world physically in doing so. Just wanted to know if this is a disadvantage of all peer-to-peer systems (is at a disadvantage at all or am I missing something?) or peer-to-peer systems does take into account some factor to do efficient routing based on actual location awareness of peers?

Answer (score 1):

There are optimizations that take latency into account, for example (among others) [vivaldi coordinates](http://swtch.com/~rsc/talks/vivaldi-ccs.pdf) which can be used to speed up lookups or preferentially connect to nodes with a lower latency.

But they significantly increase implementation complexity and vanilla DHTs already have some fairly subtle properties that are easy to get wrong so one should only implement this kind of stuff if it's really necessary.

DHTs are often used for metadata lookups (e.g. in bittorrent), thus the actual traffic they cause is fairly low.

The heavy lifting is done by direct peer-peer connections. Assuming multiple alternatives to chose from are available that choice can then be optimized based on ASN information/traceroutes/rtt-measurements, i.e. as concern separate from the DHT itself.